# Function that takes an array of letters, and combines them into words in a sentence

Tags: python

Function that takes an array of letters, and combines them into words in a sentence.
i tried this problem but i don't know, where i did my mistake.

```
import numpy as np
def arrAdder(arr):
    trans_arr= np.transpose(arrAdder)
    list1 = trans_arr.tolist()

    lis = list1[0]
    def listToString(lis):
        
        for i in range (0,  len(list1)):
            lis = list1[i]
            str1 = ""
            for ele in lis:
                str1 += ele
                return str1

    print(listToString(lis))
    return

arrAdder([['J','L','L','M'],['u','i','i','a'],['s','v','f','n'],['t','e','e','']])
```

error

> function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Using numpy seems like overkill for a problem like this. All you need is simple for-loops and str.join: `' '.join(''.join(a[i] for a in x) for i in range(len(x)))` => `'Just Live Life Man'`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Just zip it.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think for-loops should make it easier for the OP to understand to logic. Of course, there are many other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) wrote, you need to change `np.transpose(arrAdder)` to `np.transpose(arr)` because `arrAdder` is a *function*, not a *list*.

You're also using *return* incorrectly. You need to collect the string(s) first and then return.

This code returns **one string from list**:

```
import numpy as np

def arrAdder(arr):
    trans_arr= np.transpose(arr)
    list1 = trans_arr.tolist()

    lis = list1[0]
    def listToString(lis):
        string = ""
        for i in range (len(list1)):
            lis = list1[i]
            for ele in lis:
                string += ele
        
        return string

    print(listToString(lis))
    return

arrAdder([['J','L','L','M'],['u','i','i','a'],['s','v','f','n'],['t','e','e','']])
# JustLiveLifeMan
```

And this returns **list of strings**

```
import numpy as np

def arrAdder(arr):
    trans_arr= np.transpose(arr)
    list1 = trans_arr.tolist()

    lis = list1[0]
    def listToString(lis):
        stringsList = []
        for i in range (len(list1)):
            lis = list1[i]
            str1 = ""
            for ele in lis:
                str1 += ele
            stringsList.append(str1)
        
        return stringsList

    print(listToString(lis))

arrAdder([['J','L','L','M'],['u','i','i','a'],['s','v','f','n'],['t','e','e','']])
# ['Just', 'Live', 'Life', 'Man']
```

So, does it work the way you expect?

P.S.: [More about return keyword in Python](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/)